# How to get the value with VR=FL, VM=2 in Evil DICOM

Tags: c#, dicom, evil-dicom

I tried to get the Tag value by using:
`var vSAD = sel.VirtualSourceAxisDistance.Data;` 
I also tried `var vSAD = dcm.FindAll("300A030A");`
And it only returned one number (suppose to have 2).

Then I tried to read elements and save to another dicom file only and found for `VR=FL`, `VM=2` case only one number showed up in the new file.
How can I fix this to get 2 numbers?
Does it mean when I use `var dcm = DICOMFileReader.Read(openFileDialog1.FileName);`
It already return with only one number?

I saw in the FloatingPiontSingle.cs file:

```
public class FloatingPointSingle : AbstractElement<float?>
{
    public FloatingPointSingle() { }

    public FloatingPointSingle(Tag tag, float? data)
    {
        Tag = tag;
        Data = data;
        VR = Enums.VR.FloatingPointSingle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize the FL VM could be more than one. I just looked at the DICOM specification though and realize that it is possible. It is actually an easy fix. Could you post a link to a sample (anonymized) DICOM file that contains such a value and I will patch the core framework.

FYI: To patch yourself, you would need to change the `FloatingPointSingle` to:

```
public class FloatingPointSingle : AbstractElement<float[]>
{
    public FloatingPointSingle() { }

    public FloatingPointSingle(Tag tag, float[] data)
    {    
        Tag = tag;
        Data = data;
        VR = Enums.VR.FloatingPointSingle;
    }
}
```

Then in the `LittleEndianReader.ReadSinglePrecision()`, and `BigEndianReader.ReadSinglePrecision()` method you will need to change out the logic to allow concatenated floating point numbers (no delimiter).